# extracting and saving xml results in file using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle, ssis

I am trying to query results as XML from Oracle db using XMLElement and XMLAgg functions which gives me results in CLOB format. Now, when I try to use this query in Data Source flow task in SSIS, I get an error as unsupported data format.

Query:

```
select XMLElement("root",
         XMLAgg(XMLElement("person",
             XMLForest(person.first_name, person.last_name)))) AS "XMLResult"
from person
```

Question:
How do I use this query in SSIS (2008 R2) to avoid that error or any workaround. Further I need to write the results to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the result into VARCHAR or VARCHAR2 datatype as SSIS doesn't support the XML datatype.